# Can't Center Resized Large Image via CSS

Tags: html, css, resize

I'm trying to center my resized image via CSS but it doesn't seem to be working as it constantly just aligns-left.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 23.8%,
    rgba(252, 221, 221, 1) 92%
  );
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  /* z-index: 1000; */
}

img {
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}

.music-container {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px 0 rgba(252, 169, 169, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Music Player</h1>

    <div class="music-container" id="music-container">
        <div class="music-info">
            <h4 id="title"></h4>
            <div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
                <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <audio src="music/Kanye West - Father Stretch My Hands, pt. 3 () ft. Kendrick Lamar, Kid Cudi, Desiigner.mp3" id="audio"></audio>
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="images/Jil.png" alt="music-cover" id="cover">
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <button id="prev" class="action-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-backward"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="play" class="action-btn action-btn-big">
                <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="next" class="action-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks like on my end:

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkBdo.png)

I've tried utilizing the align-items center, and the justify content center as well for the image but to no avail.

Do I just have to upload a smaller image and work from there?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
#cover: {
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It made my image full screen. https://imgur.com/a/TlVHDif